# Modeling Employee-Manager relationship

Tags: database-design

Each employee in company A has a unique employee ID

A particular number of employees form a Team, eg Employees 1 - 5 form Team A

Team A, and every other team, has one manager. The manager is also an employee, with his own employee ID.

What is the best way of going to model this relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of suggestions.

**Groundwork:**

Assuming employees may be a member of more than one team, you'll want a separate employees table, a separate team table, and a table of links between the two.

### Team

- ID (PK)
- Name

### Employee

- ID (PK)
- Name

### TeamEmployees

- ID (PK)
- TeamID(FK->Team.ID)
- EmployeeID (FK->Employee.ID)

**Leader:**

Now the groundwork is in place, here are where the choices begin - you could have your leader structure:

*Team table - LeaderEmployeeID (FK->Employee.ID)*

- Advantage - one leader per team, simple
- Possible Disadvantage (depending on requirements) - leader doesn't necessarily have to be an employee who exists in the TeamEmployees table, additional checks may be required

*TeamEmployees table - IsLeader (bit)*

- Possible Advantage (depending on requirements) - leader always has to be a member of team
- Possible Disadvantage (depending on requirements) - design allows more than one leader per team, additional constraints would be needed to fix this

Comment: Ah, similar to mine but better :-) 

Thanks